# Alternatives to Dynamic Icons of Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I have read this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800259/what-good-alternatives-are-there-to-google-charts but the d3 library doesn't provide dynamic icons.
I am interested in a good alternative of the Dynamic Icons of Google Charts
( http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html )
Any suggestions??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Were you able to find an alternative? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to create the image on the server-side and then pass it to the web application.